# jQuery ajax return negative numbers instead of content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this in php:

```
return json_encode(array($raspuns, $table_licitatii, $option));
```

And this in jQuery:

```
request.done(function( msg ) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(msg);
  $("#done").html(result[0]);
  $("#table-licitatii").html(result[1]);
  $("#produs").html(result[2]);
});
```

With #done and #produs i have no problems, it's OK but in #table-licitatii instead of data(table) appear numbers(-1 -2) and on every request (-2 -2, -3 -2, -4 -2, -5 -2, -6 -2).
How can i solve this?

P.S. In #table-licitatii i have to insert somenthing like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product name</th>
                    <th>Product code</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o ceas"></i> <img src="/img/bid-icon.png" alt="Bid Icon"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                            <tr>
                    <td>TEST <small>( Amazon, Skype, PayPal)</small></td>
                    <td>LU5</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                </tr>

                            <tr>
                    <td>TESTT @@@ <small>( Amazon, Skype)</small></td>
                    <td>LU7</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: show us what you have in `$table_licitatii` by printing it out

Comment: @Anant, I edited question

Comment: have you console the json result first ?

Comment: `console.log(msg)` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `echo` your json output instead of return and then try to check your `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following and console the result:

In php:

```
  return json_encode(array($raspuns, $table_licitatii, $option));
```

to

```
  echo json_encode(array($raspuns, $table_licitatii, $option));
```